# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException in a Quartz job

Tags: grails, grails-orm, quartz-scheduler

I can use dynamic finders on my domain classes in my `Quartz` job, but get `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` when accessing relationships. I thought they would either both work, or none.

```
class MyJob {
    def author = Author.list().first() // fine
    def book = Book.get(1) // fine
    println author.books // lazy exception
}
```

Any idea why this might be happening? According to the Quartz plugin documentation each job thread gets a Hibernate session, yet I'm running into this problem.

`Grails 2.1.1`, `quartz:1.0-RC9`

Full Error:

```
2013-07-16 16:08:10,008 [quartzScheduler_Worker-10] ERROR grails.plugins.quartz.listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener  - Exception occurred in job: null
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: test.Author.books, no session or session was closed [See nested exception: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: test.Author.books, no session or session was closed]
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:96)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.QuartzDisplayJob.execute(QuartzDisplayJob.groovy:29)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: test.Author.books, no session or session was closed
    at test.MyJob$_execute_closure1$$EOBjSWum.doCall(MyJob.groovy:7)
    at test.MyJob$$EOBjSWum.execute(MyJob.groovy:7)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:89)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: I have not tested this, but try to wrap your `def author` and `author.books` lines in withSession or withTransaction closure, see if that helps

Comment: can you afford eager fetching?, not sure but just try with lazy false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MyJob` is not a grails artefact, hence not transactional by default. Associations which will be fetched lazily has to be under transactional boundary.

**Solution:-**
Follow @Alidad's comment.

```
class MyJob {
    def author = Author.list().first()
    def book = Book.get(1)
    Book.withTransaction{
        //withSession can also be used. You can also use Autor.withTransaction. 
        //The entity reference is immaterial.
        println author.books
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew that `withTransaction` would work, but I didn't expect that I would have to use it, given that there is a hibernate session provided for quartz threads. Obviously association fetching and domain querying use hibernate sessions in a way I don't understand...

Comment: Adding withTransaction worked for me but ended up with a problem in unit tests `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: gvl.cert.EvfdEmailEntry.withTransaction() is applicable for argument types: () values: []` tried switch out with withSession with same result

Comment: @aeischeid Make sure you are mocking the domain class appropriately in the Unit test case. Unless it is mocked, you wont be able to get the dynamic properties of a domain class. Use `@Mock` or `@Bind` (in case you are using build-test-data plugin)

Comment: Right, after struggling to mock it all properly I decided this was better suited for an integration test

Answer (score 0):

By default GORM single-ended associations are lazy. See [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/lazy.html) for more info.