# Can I commit inside withTransaction closure

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Can I commit inside the `withTransaction` closure? I want to do something like this inside my `Quartz` job:

```
Author.withTransaction {
    def author = Author.get(1)
    author.staus = 'processing'
    author.save()
    commit // how can i do this?
    // so some work here which takes 1-2 minutes
    author.status = 'completed'
    author.save()
}
```

The idea is that I want to have a status screen which will show all the `Author`s which are being processed at the moment, so I want to set the status to `processing` and be able to see this status from a controller.

EDIT:
This would work without `withTransaction`, but I have to have `withTransaction` there... see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669340/org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-in-a-quartz-job).

Comment: The commit will happen at the end of the each transaction.

Comment: I know that. I'm asking is there a way to do the commit inside `withTransaction`?

Comment: The job will be executed per `Author` or for a batch?

Comment: Other than the issue with lazy loading, do you need this to be transactional?

Comment: No, I made it transactional just to get around the lazy loading issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to read values from a different uncommitted transaction, your database isolation level has to be set to "read uncommitted" which is often an indicator you *might* be doing something wrong.

Is there any reason you couldn't separate this into separate transactions? One to mark the records as "in-progress" and one to perform the actual work?

```
Author.withTransaction {
    def author = Author.get(id)
    author.status = 'processing'
    author.save()
}

Author.withTransaction() {
    def author = Author.get(id)
    // do some work
    author.status = 'completed'
    author.save()
}
```

Comment: Good one. Only one question I have here, if something bad happens with the task in second transaction, how can the first transaction be rolled back?

Comment: Several ways. I would wrap this in a service method and use nested transactions. But if you wanted to stick with programmatic tx management you can catch exceptions yourself in the second transaction, use the `TransactionStatus` parameter to cause the rollback and have logic to rollback the first after the fact.

Comment: quick edit- "rollback the first" isn't quite the right terminology, as you would actually just perform another update to clear the status.

Comment: Correct you are. I agree.

Comment: That was my solution... I was just wondering if there is way to do it with one `withTransaction`. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to stick to @codelark's approach as much as I can , programmatically handling the transaction and adding logic for rollback as well.

It is a co-incident that I was also digging grounds with codelark on this question. Here is what I have now:

```
    Author.withSession{session->
        def author = Author.get(blahId)
        try{
            def tx = session.beginTransaction()
            //Update status to processing
            author.status = 'processing'
            tx.commit()

            //Do your 1 - 3 minutes task
        } catch(e){
            //If there is any exception in that task then rollback transaction
            tx?.setRollbackOnly()
        }

        if(!tx.isRollbackOnly()){
            try {
                def tx2 = session.beginTransaction()
                //Update author status to completed
                //Few pain points can also be taken care of here, like checking if the task completed as expected etc..
                author.status = 'completed'
                tx2.commit()
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                tx2?.setRollbackOnly() //If you want
            }
        }
    }
```

@Alidad is absolutely correct in saying that commit/flush happens at the end of the `withTransaction` block. So `flush: true` inside `withTransaction` would not work.